# Android Data Validation

Tags: java, android, guava

I am wondering what is the most effective form of data validation for android. So, when getting a value from an `EditText` how should the value given be validated before it is used? I currently check to make sure the string returned from `getText().toString()` is not null or empty using the guava library:

`Strings.isNullOrEmpty(editText.getText().toString())`

Then, depending on what type of data I am expecting, I create a method to see if the data can be parsed. So if I am expecting a double I will create a method like this:

```
private boolean isDouble(String string) {
    try {
        double stringDouble = Double.parseDouble(string);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is there a simpler way to do this without the need to create a separate method for each type of data I am expecting to receive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the edittext-validator the last time I needed a quick validation. Works like charm :)

https://github.com/vekexasia/android-edittext-validator

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `EditText` you should know what purposes it serves. Usually you are expecting to have just a plain string to, for example, send it to server or store in `SharedPreferences`.

But, if you want a particular data to be filled in, you can use `Pattern` class for validation. In case of number values you are using `android:inputType="number"` and when converting it using `Integer.valueOf(text)`